# How to compute the confidence interval for the Difference of Two Means with unknown variance?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance

I have to determine the 90% confidence interval for the difference of Two Means of expenses in products for the cleaning of Palace A and Palace B.
I have the following data: on a sample of 21 cleaners were detected variables:

X = monthly expenditure on cleaning products for building A

Y = monthly expenditure on cleaning products for building B,

which can be taken jointly as normal. The following summaries are obtained:

[image]

I'm not able to compute the pooled variance. Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you only have 20 observations. As far as I can tell [these steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps) are exactly what you need. Assuming of course that the observations are iid. If not clear, maybe ask more specifically which part is not clear.

Comment: @PaulG I think the point is to be able to calculate the variance of $X$ and the variance of $Y$ with only the four equations given.

Comment: Yes, you're right! My problem is how compute the variance of Y. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: You can calculate the variance of $(X-Y)$, which may be enough for testing the difference of the two means in a paired test.  If you assume independence then you can also calculate the variance of $Y$, but that may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I understand the problem is to calculate the sample variances of $X,Y$ given only this information. Let's see if it's possible (I will leave out unbiasedness denominators, i.e. $1/(n-1)$, for simplicity):

For $X$, every component is known:

$$Var[X]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i^2+(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i)^2 \tag{1}$$

For $Y$, we only know the last term explicitly.

$$Var[Y]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i^2+(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i)^2 \tag{2}$$

Let's expand the last information to see if we can deduct something from it:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{20}(x_i-y_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{20}(x_i^2-2x_iy_i+y_i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_iy_i+\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i^2 \tag{3}$$

Here we don't know the last 2 terms. So we are stuck (at least I don't see a way to solve for the latter). However, if we assume independence of $X$ and $Y$, which is sensible in this case since there's no reason to assume by default that the expenditures are individually co-dependent, then the covariance is zero, i.e.:

$$Cov[X,Y]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_iy_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}(x_i)\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}(y_i) \overset{!}{=}0$$

Solving for the first term leads to:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_iy_i = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i \\
\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{20}x_iy_i = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i \\
$$

Now plugging this into $(3)$ leads to

$$\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i^2$$

which can now be solved for the last term:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{20}(x_i-y_i)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i^2 + 2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{20}x_i\sum_{i=1}^{20}y_i
$$

which in turn can be used for the variance of $Y$, i.e. $(2)$.

EDIT: @Henry mentions in a comment on the OP that you can calculate the variance of $X-Y$ directly, which is true and makes my answer somewhat of over-engineering. :) Just fyi: You would treat the difference as a random variable $Z=X-Y$ and then apply the variance formula $(1)$ and replace $x_i$ with $x_i-y_i$. Obviously all info is given since $\sum (x_i-y_i)=\sum x_i - \sum y_i$.

Comment: PaulG & Henry: Thank you both very much for your help! Now it’s clear!

Comment: Though now that I think about it I'm not sure what effect would dependency between $X,Y$ have when calculating the difference. If they're independent it should lead to the same answer since $Var[X-Y]=Var[X]+Var[Y]$ (under independence)